# Connecting to local sql server in vb.net - Error Connecting and difference between Local and Commercial?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am a developer building websites in VB.Net using Visual Studio 2010. I am trying to populate some fields when a user visits a website based on their decisions on a previous screen.

My connection information is as follows:

```
Dim myDataReader As SqlDataReader
Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
Dim strSQL As String

myConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress; Database=PREP; Integrated Security=SSPI;")
Try
    myConnection.Open()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Charts where ID=1"

myCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, myConnection)

myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

If myDataReader.Read() Then
    TextBox1.Text = myDataReader.Item("Priority1")
Else
    MsgBox("Didn't work...")
End If
```

The error I continue to get is:

> Cannot open database "PREP" by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'OR-AA-Me\Me'

I assumed that since it was a local database I would not need a username and password. Am I wrong?

Also, are there glaring practices in the above code that will be unwise when I transport this to a commercial environment?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide the username, also, assuming you have a local database, your data source should be localhost only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

The connection string simply needed additional filepath information.

The successful connection information was:

> myConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PREP.mdf; Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True")

There was no need for a username as the Integrated Security set to True assumes that the computer will use the login information for the user on the actual computer he is using.

---